# Intellij - see where an implicit session is coming from

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

In the following

```
DB.withSession {
   implicit session =>
     val user = users.filter(user => user.email === email 
       && user.password === password).first
 }
```

How can I get IntelliJ to show me where the implicit session is defined?

Answer (score 2):

Put cursor on the expression and press `Ctrl+Shift+P` if you're on the default Intellij keyboard layout. Or through the menu, `View` -> `Implicit parameters`.

Answer (score 1):

`session`is defined in `withSession` and gets passed into the closure as the argument. Try to zoom into `withSession`.

So the `session` gets `implicit` in the closure, and thus gets (probably) passed implicitly to `users.filter`.

---

The non-implicit version possibly looks like this (haven't really checked/compiled it though):

```
DB.withSession {
   session =>
     val user = users.filter(user => user.email === email 
       && user.password === password)(session).first
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`withSession` could be implemented like this (very simplified)

```
def withSession(f: Session => Unit) {
  val session = getSession()
  f(session)
}
```

So creators of this method allowed you to do some actions on database, and they provide you session object, without you needing to know how it is created. You need to pass a function that uses this session to do whatever  you need.

```
DB.withSession { session => /* use your session here */ }
```

In addition you can say that this value bounded to session is implicit. Just like you can replace

```
val number = 3
```

with

```
implicit val number = 3
```

number becomes implicit and compiler can put it as an implicit parameter to method that requires it.

In exactly the same way you can make session an implicit value

```
DB.withSession { implicit session => /* use your session here */ }
```

If any method requires implicit parameter of type `Session` inside your function, compiler will put `session` in there.

To answer this:

> How can I get IntelliJ to show me where the implicit session is defined?

in this exact case you don't need to go anywhere. Implicit session is defined right in this line

```
DB.withSession {
  implicit session => // <<<<<
    val user = users.filter(user => user.email === email 
      && user.password === password).first
}
```

If you want to see how is this session created and passed to your function you should go to sources of `withSession` using for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> and you will eventually find out. But it has nothing to do with implicits.